# Summarize Custom Array in Java based on its value. (Not to sum (Adding)), but just concatenate

Tags: java, android

How to get summarized value on the basis of its value in Custom Arraylist in Java, android.
summarized, not adding but concatenate.

my array is

```
  HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<TallyDaybookModal> summaryModals = new ArrayList<>();
    summaryModals.add(new TallyDaybookModal("a", "a1", "2", "3", "4"));
    summaryModals.add(new TallyDaybookModal("a", "b5", "6", "7", "8"));
    summaryModals.add(new TallyDaybookModal("a", "c5", "6", "7", "8"));
    summaryModals.add(new TallyDaybookModal("b", "15", "16", "17", "18"));
    summaryModals.add(new TallyDaybookModal("b", "9", "10", "11", "12"));
```

**sumVoucherModal**

```
public static ArrayList<TallyDaybookModal> sumVoucherModal(ArrayList<TallyDaybookModal> tallyDaybookModals) {
    Map<String, TallyDaybookModal> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (TallyDaybookModal summaryModal : tallyDaybookModals) {
        String voucher = summaryModal.getRemarks();
        TallyDaybookModal sum = map.get(voucher);
        if (sum == null) {
            sum = new TallyDaybookModal(voucher, "", "", "", "");
            map.put(voucher, sum);
        }
        sum.setDt1(sum.getDt1() + summaryModal.getDt1());
        sum.setDt2(sum.getDt2() + summaryModal.getDt2());
        sum.setDt3(sum.getDt3() + summaryModal.getDt3());
        sum.setDt4(sum.getDt4() + summaryModal.getDt4());
    }
    return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
}
```

**My approach**

```
for (TallyDaybookModal modal : sumVoucherModal(summaryModals)) {
        String rm = modal.getRemarks();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String dt1 = modal.getDt1();
        String dt2 = modal.getDt2();
        String dt3 = modal.getDt3();
        String dt4 = modal.getDt4();
        
        list.add(dt1);
        list.add(dt2);
        list.add(dt3);
        list.add(dt4);

        map.put(rm, list);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

*Expected out:* `{a = [a1234, b5678],b=15161718, 9101112]}`

but i am getting `{a=[a1b5c5, 266, 377, 488], b=[159, 1610, 1711, 1812]}`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I Have an array of summaryModal, as given in this question at the very first, which has too many data to summarize.
from that array, i want to get filtered with reference of first value **a or b**.
I want to have result with mapkey **a** and its value should be in list with the object having **a** at first from the modalArraylist as **{a = [a1234, b5678],b=15161718, 9101112]}**
but i got **{a=[a1b5c5, 266, 377, 488], b=[159, 1610, 1711, 1812]}**

Comment: please help me if there is a solution, I am really stocked here for many days